# Adding Rotten Tomates API to iphone app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Im trying to add Rotten Tomatoes API to my app but it doesn't seem to like it? What am I doing wrong?? The error says "Data Argument not used by format string"

```
-(void)main {
    NSLog(@"Service has run");
    NSString *api_key = @"j4jz49tvf76cmnb4mwfyjvyt";
    NSString *search_term = [searchTerm stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists/movies/box_office.json?limit=16&country=us&apikey=j4jz49tvf76cmnb4mwfyjvyt", api_key, search_term];

    NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]
                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
                              NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil];

                              if (responseData !=nil) {
                                  NSError *error =nil;
                                  NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                                                         options:kNilOptions error:&error];
                                  if (error) {
                                      [delegate serviceFinished:self withError:YES];
                                  } else {
                                      results = (NSArray *) [json valueForKey:@"movies"];
                                      [delegate serviceFinished:self withError:NO];
                                  }
                              } else {
                                  [delegate serviceFinished:self withError:YES];
                              }
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is on this line

```
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists/movies/box_office.json?limit=16&country=us&apikey=j4jz49tvf76cmnb4mwfyjvyt", api_key, search_term];
```

String with format works with adding a data argument like `%@` in a string as a placeholder, and then replacing that with the following arguments in your method call.

What you want to do is probably something like:

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists/movies/box_office.json?limit=16&country=us&apikey=%@&search_term=%@", api_key, search_term];
```

Comment: Ahhh, Thanks for the help, the tutorials that were provided by my university instructed me to write it how I originally had it. However my app still wont fetch the list of movies from rotten tomatoes even after the code change. Any idea to why this is?

Comment: I didn't make the correct URL, I just provided an example on how it's probably supposed to me formatted. I'd suggest reading http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/docs the developer docs, assuming you have a basic understanding of programming.